# I do not separate the words by means of split in array

Tags: java, file, buffer, filereader

My current problem is how you can read text files with java but that contain the pipes "|" And that in each separation I get the word that is contained in them.

Code To read now:

```
   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String separado[] = sCurrentLine.split("|");
        for (int i = 0; i < sCurrentLine.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(separado[i]);
        }

       // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
```

Text File Structure I Must Read:

```
Walther|28|M
Martha|28|F
Julio|28|M
```

The current result is:

```
W
a
l
t
h
e
r
|
2
8
|
M
M
a
r
t
h
a
|
2
8
|
F
J
u
l
i
o
|
2
8
|
M
```

I try to change the next line `sCurrentLine.length()` for this line `separado.lenght` But I got the following error `cannot find symbol variable separado of type String[]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `|` in your split expression as that is a regular expression. Something like this would be better:

```
String separado[] = sCurrentLine.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String separado[] = sCurrentLine.split("\\|");
    for (int i = 0; i < separado.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(separado[i]);
    }
}
```